# Generic widget unable to infer Type for callback function

Tags: flutter, dart, generics, type-inference

Im trying to create a generic Widget that takes in a value of type T and a callback function with parameter of type T like this:

```
class TestWidget<T> extends StatelessWidget {
  final T value;
  final Function(T) callback;

  const TestWidget({
    super.key,
    required this.value,
    required this.callback,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

When trying to use the widget, like this

```
MyClass value = MyClass();
TestWidget(
  value: value,
  callback: (callbackValue) {},
);
```

Everything works fine except the infered type for `callbackValue` is `Object?` even though the infered type for callback is `dynamic Function(MyClass)`

changing the callback function to

```
(MyClass callbackValue) {},
```

does work and causes no issues however i would like not to have to manually add the type

Changing the callback function to anything else, for example

```
(String callbackValue) {}
```

does cause an error saying *The argument type 'Null Function(String)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'dynamic Function(MyClass)'*
so the type infered for T is clearly correct.

Is there anyway i can change my widget to avoid having to explicitly type the function?

Comment: As noted in the linked answer, see https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/731.  This situation should be better when Dart 2.18 ships.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inform the type in the header to assign the type within the class at runtime, for this the nomenclature `<T>` within the class is used.

```
MyClass value = MyClass();
TestWidget<MyClass>(
  value: value,
  callback: (callbackValue) {},
);
```